# how do you write multiple objects to a plist at different times as well as delete the entries?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, plist, xcode4.3

My program has a tableView with a list of entries that and you can add each item in the table View to the "favorites."  I have been storing the information in a plist however i'm not sure if it is possible to store multiple objects at different times or will it continue to over write the plist with the new entry?  Also is it possible to delete the entries out of the plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having a bit of trouble understanding your question.

How are you storing your data?

A. If your data is in an NSArray\NSMutableArray You can call `writeToFile:` on your array to save the current state of your array, then after you modify your array ether inserting or deleting items you can call `writeToFile:` to update your plist. NSMutableArray will allow you to do all those modifications.

B. if you want more low level control you can parce the XML plist. But this will be a lot more work...

Comment: well it is in a NSMutableArray and I am calling writeToFile: the only problem is there are multiple entries and every time you click a different one it saves over the last entry, is there a way to write to the plist without saving over the last entry and the prior NSMutableArray is still obtained.

Comment: Ok so you want to basicalty log and keep on adding to the file? You could 1.load the plist to a new NSMutableArray. 2. Append your NSMutableArray to the end of that array. 3. Save the array you loaded and apended to into your plist.